# How to map elements to themselves with an 'identitity' label in python?

Tags: python, import, label, mapping, identity

Right now I have:

```
label = {"A" : 1, "B" : 2}
x = np.zeros((150,4))
y = np.zeros(150)
i = 0

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    print(next(reader, None))
    for row in reader:
        x[i,:] = row[1:5]
        y[i] = label[row[5]] #it's about this line
        i += 1
```

But if the row contains 1, 2 or 3 it throws an error because there is no mapping from them.

```
KeyError: '3'
```

How do I map them to themselves without adding them into the label specifically?
Is there such thing as an identity label that maps all elements to themselves?

Comment: Can you provide desired output to help make the question clearer?

Comment: `label.get(row[5], row[5])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own dictionary class:

```
class id_dict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key

labels = id_dict({"A" : 1, "B" : 2})

print(labels["A"])
print(labels[3])
```

Output will be

```
1
3
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I had no idea I could do this. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works for you. :) But actually for your use case `label.get(row[5], row[5])` as suggested by Rawing would work too.

Comment: Why does id_dict() return its input if it is not missing? in my head you don't define that so it should just output nothing at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "return its input if it is not missing"? Can you give an example?

Comment: I pass the labels into the constructor: `labels = id_dict({"A" : 1, "B" : 2})`

Comment: I understand that 

    `{"A" : 1, "B" : 2}['A']==1`

but I don't understand why 

    `id_dist({"A" : 1, "B" : 2})['A']==1`

Why does id_dist output anything? To me it looks as if there is nothing defined so it should outputs nothing. There is probably a very fundamental flaw in my thinking but I can't find it.

Comment: see this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict  `If a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping object.`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, if you try to access `label[3]` and the key doesn't exist, you want `label[3] = 3`?

You could build a custom `defaultdict` factory that inserted the key value pair into your label dict... possibly.  See comment below

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory

Or if the key doesn't exist you can return a default value

`label.get(key, default_value)`

Finally, you could just do a simple try/except block

```
try: 
    y[i] = label[row[5]]
except:
    do something
```

Comment: I think the default_factory is not called with the key as argument. So you cannot insert the key there.